# Wordpress: Adding further code to wp_nav_menu output

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, nav

I'm currently using a custom menu within Wordpress and I'm wanting the code that is outputted to include a span inside the link tag.

The result I am looking for is:

```
<ul class="quicklinks">
    <li class="custom-class"><a href="#">Link 1<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
    <li class="custom-class"><a href="#">Link 2<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
    <li class="custom-class"><a href="#">Link 3<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm currently using the following:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu' => 'Quicklinks 1',
    'theme_location' => 'quicklinks-home',
    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
    'items_wrap' => '<ul class="quicklink">%3$s</ul>'
)); ?>
```

Which results in:

```
<ul class="quicklinks">
    <li class="custom-class"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="custom-class"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="custom-class"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried to alter the items_wrap part of the code above. However, I'm getting mixed results and it removes the ability to add in a custom CSS class. I don't think I'm a million miles away... just need a little help to get over the line.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the `wp_nav_menu` reference at

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu.

See, the `link_after` parameter.